# String split in R skipping first delimiter if multiple delimiters are present

Tags: regex, r

I have "`elephant_giraffe_lion`" and "`monkey_tiger`" strings.
The condition here is if there are two or more delimiters, I want to split at the second delimiter and if there is only one delimiter, I want to split at that delimiter. So the results I want to get in this example are "`elephant_giraffe`" and "`monkey`".

```
mystring<-c("elephant_giraffe_lion", "monkey_tiger")
```

result

```
"elephant_giraffe"  "monkey"
```

Comment: What about 'foo_bar_baz_bap' ? Do you want 'foo_bar' as output?

Comment: yes I want "foo_bar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can anchor your split to the end of the string using `$`,

```
unlist(strsplit(mystring, "_[a-z]+$"))
# [1] "elephant_giraffe" "monkey"
```

#### Edit

The above only matches the last "_", not accounting for cases where there are more than two "_".  For the more general case, you could try

```
mystring<-c("elephant_giraffe_lion", "monkey_tiger", "dogs", "foo_bar_baz_bap")

tmp <- gsub("([^_]+_[^_]+).*", "\\1", mystring)
tmp[tmp==mystring] <- sapply(strsplit(tmp[tmp==mystring], "_"), `[[`, 1)
tmp
# [1] "elephant_giraffe" "monkey"           "dogs"             "foo_bar"
```

You could also use `gsubfn`, to process the match with a function

```
library(gsubfn)
f <- function(x,y) if (y==x) strsplit(y, "_")[[1]][[1]] else y
gsubfn("([^_]+_[^_]+).*", f, mystring, backref=1)
# [1] "elephant_giraffe" "monkey"           "dogs"             "foo_bar"
```

Comment: Thanks! what do I need to do if the part to be eliminated have alpha-numeric and both upper lower cases?

Comment: I mean with this:_[a-z]+$

Comment: @user277653 you can add the other cases into the brackets, ie. `[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Comment: Note this splits at the _last_ delimiter rather than the _second_ or only delimiter. Examples in the question do not cover other cases.

Answer (score 1):

As I posted an answer on your other related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931954/string-split-with-conditions-in-r), a base R solution:

```
x <- c('elephant_giraffe_lion', 'monkey_tiger', 'foo_bar_baz_bap')
sub('^(?|([^_]*_[^_]*)_.*|([^_]*)_[^_]*)$', '\\1', x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "elephant_giraffe" "monkey"           "foo_bar"
```