# String split with conditions in R

Tags: regex, r, string, split

I have this `mystring` with the delimiter `_`. The condition here is if there are two or more delimiters, I want to split at the second delimiter and if there is only one delimiter, I want to split at `".Recal"` and get the `result` as shown below.

```
mystring<-c("MODY_60.2.ReCal.sort.bam","MODY_116.21_C4U.ReCal.sort.bam","MODY_116.3_C2RX-1-10.ReCal.sort.bam","MODY_116.4.ReCal.sort.bam")
```

result

```
"MODY_60.2"  "MODY_116.21" "MODY_116.3"  "MODY_116.4"
```

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know if there's a way to do it in one go. I can hack it like `sub("(.+_.+)_.+$", "\\1", sub("\\.ReCal.+$", "", mystring))` , but I'm sure someone can improve that.

Comment: Mimicking the logic in terms of regexes, maybe like this: `sub("(?(?=.+_.+_)(.+_.+)_.*|(.+)\\.ReCal.*)", "\\1\\2", mystring, perl = TRUE)`.

Comment: If you do manage to get this in one regex or even employ @nongkrong's solution, _please_ stick a comment above the code so your future self (or some person who becomes the caretaker) knows what you were trying to do. I've bitten myself a few times with a "very clever solution" that my younger self crafted that took ages to remember the details of/reasoning behind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
f <- function(x,y,z) if (z=="_") y else strsplit(x, ".ReCal", fixed=T)[[1]][[1]]
gsubfn("([^_]+_[^_]+)(.).*", f, mystring, backref=2)
# [1] "MODY_60.2"   "MODY_116.21" "MODY_116.3"  "MODY_116.4"
```

This allows for cases when you have more than two "_", and you want to split on the second one, for example,

```
mystring<-c("MODY_60.2.ReCal.sort.bam",
            "MODY_116.21_C4U.ReCal.sort.bam",
            "MODY_116.3_C2RX-1-10.ReCal.sort.bam",
            "MODY_116.4.ReCal.sort.bam",
            "MODY_116.4_asdfsadf_1212_asfsdf",
            "MODY_116.5.ReCal_asdfsadf_1212_asfsdf",  # split by second "_", leaving ".ReCal"
            "MODY")

gsubfn("([^_]+_[^_]+)(.).*", f, mystring, backref=2)
# [1] "MODY_60.2"        "MODY_116.21"      "MODY_116.3"       "MODY_116.4"      
# [5] "MODY_116.4"       "MODY_116.5.ReCal" "MODY"
```

In the function, `f`, `x` is the original string, `y` and `z` are the next matches.  So, if `z` is not a "_", then it proceeds with the splitting by the alternative string.

Comment: Could you please explain what these numbers here are: [[1]][[1]]; and this structure:("([^_]+_[^_]+)(.).*", f, mystring, backref=2)

Comment: @MAPK the `[[1]][[1]]` is indexing the result returned by `strsplit`, to take the first part of the returned split.  The "[^_]+" regex means 'match anything not equal to a "\_"'.  So, the first part of the regex (contained in the first set of "( )") matches up until the second "\_", if there is one. The "(.)" matches the next character, to check if there was a second "_" (this match corresponds to `z` in the function `f`).

Answer (score 5):

With the `stringr` package:

```
str_extract(mystring, '.*?_.*?(?=_)|^.*?_.*(?=\\.ReCal)')
[1] "MODY_60.2" "MODY_116.21" "MODY_116.3" "MODY_116.4"
```

It also works with more than two delimiters.

Answer (score 5):

Perl/PCRE has the **branch reset** feature that lets you reuse a group number when you have capturing groups in different alternatives, and is considered as one capturing group.

IMO, this feature is elegant when you want to supply different alternatives.

```
x <- c('MODY_60.2.ReCal.sort.bam', 'MODY_116.21_C4U.ReCal.sort.bam', 
       'MODY_116.3_C2RX-1-10.ReCal.sort.bam', 'MODY_116.4.ReCal.sort.bam',
       'MODY_116.4_asdfsadf_1212_asfsdf', 'MODY_116.5.ReCal_asdfsadf_1212_asfsdf', 'MODY')

sub('^(?|([^_]*_[^_]*)_.*|(.*)\\.ReCal.*)$', '\\1', x, perl=T)
# [1] "MODY_60.2"        "MODY_116.21"      "MODY_116.3"       "MODY_116.4"      
# [5] "MODY_116.4"       "MODY_116.5.ReCal" "MODY"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
gsub('^(.*\\.\\d+).*','\\1',mystring)
[1] "MODY_60.2"   "MODY_116.21" "MODY_116.3"  "MODY_116.4"
```

Comment: That works, but doesn't employ the desired logic. You're looking at the example string and reinterpreting the pattern to identify. You should at least provide more explanation as to how this is working.

Answer (score 2):

```
^([^_\\n]*_[^_\\n]*)(?:_.*|\\.ReCal[^_]*)$
```

You can simply do using `gsub` without using any complex regex.Just replace by `\\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wL4aB6/1

Answer (score 2):

A little longer, but needs less regular expression knowledge:

```
library(stringr)
indx <- str_locate_all(mystring, "_")

for (i in seq_along(indx)) {
  if (nrow(indx[[i]]) == 1) {
    mystring[i] <- strsplit(mystring[i], ".ReCal")[[1]][1]
  } else {
    mystring[i] <- substr(mystring[i], start = 1, stop = indx[[i]][2] - 1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`gregexpr` can search for a pattern in strings and give the location.

First, we use `gregexpr` to find the location of all `_` in each element of `mystring`. Then, we loop through that output and extract the index of second `_` within each element of `mystring`. If there is no second `_`, it'll return an `NA` (check `inds` in the example below).

After that, we can either extract the relevant part using `substr` based on the extracted index or, if there is `NA`, we can split the string at `.ReCal` and keep only the first part.

```
inds = sapply(gregexpr("_", mystring, fixed = TRUE), function(x) x[2])
ifelse(!is.na(inds),
       substr(mystring, 1, inds - 1), 
       sapply(strsplit(mystring, ".ReCal"), '[', 1))
#[1] "MODY_60.2"   "MODY_116.21" "MODY_116.3"  "MODY_116.4"
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code your provided answers the question.